# Can anyone dissamble a android or a iphone app , so i can see who programmed it please

Tags: android

i am looking for some help , i have a app i like in the android market place , they also have the same app in the apple marketplace to , its a free download , but i would like to know who programmed it for the company that is using it .

Anyone help me on this one please , or can anyone provide the service for me ?!

Answer (score 1):

Even if someone can disassemble the code and get to something that is meaningful, I don't think that it is possible to see WHO programmed it, except if somehow he managed to put his name on the code or something like that. What could you do with that information anyway apart from blackmailing for some reason?

Comment: What else could be done? Many things, Eg he could offer them a job.

You are correct (so +1).
Perhaps you could impove you anser by explaining that while many (most?) authors will put there name into the soucre code as a comment, decompiling it will not restore comments to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely the developer included their name in the binary, but if they did, you can find it with a tool like [Strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) in Windows or the command [strings](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) in Linux. No disassembling required.

Alternatively, you can contact the company that released the app and ask them who developed it. It's worth a try.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your reply , i have no idea why theoxarhs thinks i would like to blackmail a devolper ?!?! i would not be asking for money from them , i would be hoping to pay them to develop me a similar App !!      I cannot really contact the business that is using the app as they will not tell me where it was made ,as they are a small business , who would not want to give away such info...i have dissamebled the code and had a look through using the beta of Android  stuido , but nothing really in there , is there a particular part of the libarys that might contain the info ?!?